# Can I place a button on the mobile native player when playing in Livecode?

Tags: android, livecode

I create mobile native player in the full screen, and I want to place a button on the mobile native player for callback original size.

Here code for create mobile native player:

```
on mouseUp
   lock screen
   set the visible of img "poster" to false
   mobileControlCreate "player", "vdoplayer"
   put the result into pID
   mobileControlSet pID,"filename" , specialFolderpath("engine") & "/vdo.mp4" 
   mobileControlSet pID,"preserveAspect" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"showController" , true 
   mobileControlSet pID,"fullscreen" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"looping" , true
   mobileControlSet pID,"rect" , the rect of this card
   mobileControlSet pID,"visible" , true
   mobileControlDo pID,"play"
   unlock screen
end mouseUp
```

I test on the operating system Android.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, native controls created using mobileControlCreate sit on top of all LiveCode controls on your stack so it's not possible to do what you are trying to do I'm afraid.